# Battery Cabling for a DC Power Plant

Tags: voltage, dc, low-power, cables

Battery cabling shall be sized as follows:
For a single plant: Battery cabling shall be sized to the greater of a 2-hour
discharge rate for ampacity or a 5-hour discharge rate for the voltage drop

Batteries: Deka AVR125-33

5 Hr. Discharge Rate: 352 Amps

2 Hr. Discharge Rate: 696 Amps

11.1=Constant for copper cable,
AVD=Allowable Voltage Drop,
LL=Loop Length, 
CM=Circular Mills

Allowable Ampacity at 75 Degree C for 750MCM=475A

**2 Hr. Calc**=11.1*696A*40LL/.25AVD=1,236,096CM/750,000CM=1.64(2)750 MCM Cables per polarity

**Voltage Drop**=11.1*696A*40LL/1,500,000CM(2-750MCM Cables)=.21VD

**5 Hr. Calc**=11.1*352A*40LL/.25AVD=625,152/750,000CM=.83(1)750 MCM Cable per polarity

**Voltage Drop**=11.1*352A*40LL/750,000CM(1-750MCM Cable)=.21VD

What exactly do they mean by a 5-hour discharge rate for the voltage drop? I,m assuming I would go with the 2 Hr. choice since there would be more cabling involved. Will there ever be a situation that the 5 Hr. calculation will be greater? Since the amperage for a 5 Hr. discharge rate will always be lower than a 2 Hr.

Comment: The answer to your first question is that you have to work out the 5hr discharge rate and then, using the resistance of the cable calculate the voltage drop - this answer is compared to the answer fron the 2hr calculation based on the ampacity : then take the larger of the two...

Comment: @Solar Mike put that up as an answer it makes the second question moot.

Comment: @RoyC just seen the quote on your profile - where does that come from? It's very good...

Comment: @Solar Mike One of those Fau Zen things I came across more years ago than I care to remember.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is that you have to work out the 5hr discharge rate and then, using the resistance of the cable, calculate the voltage drop - this answer is compared to the answer from the 2hr calculation based on the ampacity : then take the larger of the two...

Based on your comment:
The results will differ based on the cables used for each calculation : if you use the same cable then as you mention the 5 hr average will be lower than the 2 hr average but the 2 hr average will need a larger and more expensive cable...

Comment: Thank you for your answer Solar Mike. Can you give an example of a situation that the 5 Hr. calculation will be greater?

Comment: If you size the cable for each situation and do all the calcs the results should show you. It does depend on how much you want to spend on cable : thicker copper costs more...

Comment: cost of the cable is not a concern...

Comment: correct sizing is.

Answer (score 0):

The **Ampacity limit** is defined by thermal power loss per unit length or current limited by temperature rise  and thus limited the diameter of the wire but not the length.

The **Voltage drop** criteria is limited by the V=IR, so becomes a function of length , where Gauge wire is defined resistance per unit length.

Thus a long cable could easily increase the wire gauge based on voltage drop yet still be under the ampacity rating.

Comment: Tony, this makes sense but wouldn't this only change if the ampacity remained the same?

Comment: No, these are 2 independent criteria. Here they chose 2 cables for ~700A (2h) and 1 cable for ~350A (5H) which  used different total Ampacity but had exactly the same V drop.

Comment: but the cables were  10x longer   then the 5h rate might have needed 10 such cables in parallel and would have been the bigger requirement.  Is that clear now?

Comment: I did the calculations the same because they are both for the same string of batteries(new install), which is going to remain the same distance from the power plant. The distances will never be different.

Comment: 0.5% V drop is reasonable.

Comment: The customers allowable voltage drop is .25VDC that can not be changed or be above that limit.